# Não é possível acessar os valores do produto em C

Tags: c

Na função estoque_imprimir, não é possível acessar os valores do produto, ocasionando no seguinte erro:
[image: Texto]

### tad_estoque.c

```
#include "tad_estoque.h"

#define TAM 100

struct estoque
{
    char descricao[50];
    Produto *vetor[TAM];
    int qtde;
};
void estoque_imprimir(Estoque *e)
{
    printf("[");
    for (int i = 0; i < e->qtde; i++)
    {
        printf("(%d, %s, %2.f)", e->vetor[i]->codigo, e->vetor[i]->descricao, e->vetor[i]->preco);
    }
    printf("]\n");
}
```

### tad_estoque.h

```
#ifndef _TAD_ESTOQUE_
#define _TAD_ESTOQUE_

#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "tad_produto.h"

/********************************************
 * DADOS
********************************************/
typedef struct estoque Estoque;

/********************************************
 * OPERAÇÕES
********************************************/

Estoque* estoque_criar(char* descricao);

void estoque_destruir(Estoque** endEstoque);

bool estoque_anexar(Estoque* e, Produto* p);

int estoque_remover_elemento(Estoque* e, char* descricao);

void estoque_imprimir(Estoque* e);

#endif
```

### tad_produto.c

```
#include "tad_produto.h"

struct produto
{
    int codigo;
    char descricao[50];
    double ultimos_precos[4]; // armazena no máximo os últimos 4 preços praticados
    int qtd_precos;           // quantidade de preços armazenados no vetor ultimos_precos
};
```

### tad_produto.h

```
#ifndef _TAD_PRODUTO_
#define _TAD_PRODUTO_

#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

/********************************************
 * DADOS
********************************************/
typedef struct produto Produto;

/********************************************
 * OPERAÇÕES
********************************************/
Produto* produto_criar(int codigo, char* descricao, double preco);

void produto_destruir(Produto** endProduto);

int produto_codigo(Produto* p);

bool produto_descricao(Produto* p, char* saida);

double produto_preco(Produto* p);

double produto_media_preco(Produto* p);

bool produto_altera_preco(Produto* p, double preco);

#endif
```

PS: O arquivo tad_estoque.h inclui o tad_produto.h

Comment: O que tem dentro do `tad_produto.h` e o do `tad_estoque.h`?

Comment: O esqueleto do tad_produto.c e tad_estoque.c (Por exemplo, na .h está typedef struct estoque Estoque; e na .c está a estrutura completa, além de estar incluindo bibliotecas para implementação.

Comment: Teria como você adicionar ele na postagem para podermos ver e debugar melhor?

Comment: Vou editar aqui

Comment: Inclui ambos os arquivos .h
A parte oculta dos tads.c são a implementação do .h

Comment: Como está a sua main?

Comment: Seu código está no github por acaso? OU replit? Se sim poderia compartilhar?

Comment: acabei de upar. (no caso do tad_produto.c, eu não tenho acesso, eu recebi o arquivo compilado apenas)
https://replit.com/@mattokgit44/Complemento-para-o-StackOverflow#Exercicio03/tad_estoque.c

Comment: Estou analisando aqui, mas já vejo que tem muitos erros no seu código.

Comment: Eu estava no começo do exercício, mas como não consegui acessar a struct dentro do vetor, acabei deixando todo o resto de lado até achar a solução (sem progresso até o momento)

Comment: Opa, consegui resolver a questão do acesso à struct e finalizei o exercício sem erros de compilação, agradeço muito pela ajuda, Vagner!

Answer (score 0):

O problema se encontrava no arquivo tad_produto.h, onde a implementação do struct, juntamente com uma condição
#ifndef *TAD_PRODUTO*
resolvia.

Código:

```c
#ifndef _TAD_PRODUTO_
#define _TAD_PRODUTO_

typedef struct produto
{
  int codigo;
  char descricao[50];
  double ultimos_precos[4];
  int qtd_precos;
} Produto;

//restante do código oculto

#endif
```